job_start() run a command to render a pdf but it takes time to render and then the next command is ignored
Consider the following use-case where the first command open a pdf viewer and the second resize and move the newly created window:
  vim9script

  # ...
  var open_file_cmd = $'zathura --config-dir=$HOME/.config/zathura --fork example.pdf'
  var move_and_resize_cmd = $'xdotool search --onlyvisible --name example.pdf windowsize 900 1000 windowmove 1000 0'
  silent job_start(open_file_cmd)
  sleep 100m
  silent job_start(move_and_resize_cmd)

That works well, but I really don't like that sleep 100m. I would rather use a callback that resize and move the window once the pdf finished to render. How to do that?
I was thinking to replace system(open_file_cmd) with job_start(open_file_cmd) and call an appropriate callback, but I really have no idea which callback may be useful in this use-case.

If the zathura job doesn’t exit or provide a way to log information so that other processes can respond to events, then there probably isn’t a callback you can use
